# Rails require external ruby file containing configuration variables at runtime (variable name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, global-variables

When exporting my data to Excel, I prompt the user to select his export template.

Each export template **should be a separate (ruby) file** that contains several parameters.

I tried to "require" my file after selects it from a drop-down list but the variables that the ruby file contains are not accessible.

**What is the best solution to include a ruby file at runtime, depending on the previous user's choice ?**

The goal is to include different set of parameters at runtime

My code :

```
Class ExportController < ApplicationController
...
def step3
    filepath = params[:template][:filepath]
    if File.exists?(file=File.join(Rails.root, filepath))
        logger.debug ("-----------> File FOUND : "+file.to_s)    
                     # This gives:  File FOUND : D:/Rails/test1/lib/export/test2.rb
        require file
    else
        logger.debug ("-----------> File not found !!")
    end

end
```

File test2.rb :

```
@test = "Hello world"
```

In the view :

```
<%= @test.to_s %>
```

gives nothing... :-(

Answer (score 0):

I thing that what you need to do is call eval on the file's content.

It's not a very good idea though... It evaluates ruby code runtime.

Ex (in a rails console):

```
>eval('@test = 450')
>  450
>@test
>  450
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this would be going to resolve your problem. But as per What I understand is you need to generate template dynamically for your excel export. I suggest you to have a look of [ERB templating](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html). In this you will find how you can generate templates dynamically then you can render them in rails.

Hope I have understood correctly and this answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I chose to import a configuration file coded in YAML. This seems the best way to import variables depending on a user's choice (load a different yaml file at runtime)